# Download and Install TortoiseSVN on Mac Machine

Tags: macos, installation, download, tortoisesvn

I am using macOS Catalina and Version : 10.15.7.
Can anyone tell me how to download the Tortoise SVN and install in my Mac machine.

Thank you.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a Windows only software. Use tools like [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/download/)

Comment: Thank you.Can you please send the free tools for SVN.

Comment: I don't use MacOS